# How To Read A Single Value From An Azure Table?

Tags: azure, windows-store-apps

I am currently using this method to retrieve one value from my table in Azure.

```
int id = 15;

List<Person> pList = await App.MobileService.GetTable<Person>().Where(
                person => person.id == 15).ToListAsync();

foreach(Person pers in pList)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pers.firstName);
}
```

Is there a better way of retrieving **one single value** from Azure database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LookupAsync(ObjectID)` method. It is defined in the `IMobileServiceTable` Interface.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.imobileservicetable.lookupasync.aspx

So you could do something like `myTable.LookupAsync(person.ID)` - this will return your requested object or throw an exception if it fails to find a record with the specified ID.

Comment: Awesome! `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine((await App.MobileService.GetTable<Patient>().LookupAsync(1) as Patient).firstName);` worked. Thank you very much!